# creating a widget that returns two widget but have delayed/timer

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I create a Widget that first show like `Uploading please wait...` and after a delayed it would say `Successfully Uploaded` there are no databases yet, so I just want to add some delay into it and if possible would be great if it would be reusable.

```
Widget staticMessageGenerator(delayedMessage, currentMessage) {
    // Text here
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () {
    // remove the return below and add Text Widget after the Future.delayed like
    // Text(delayedMessage);
      },
    );

    return Text(currentMessage);
  }
```

Comment: Please perform basic research before asking questions. See `FutureBuilder`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I won't recommend creating method while it just return the FutureBuilder. And the main issue it can recall the api on every changes.

```dart
Widget staticMessageGenerator(delayedMessage, currentMessage) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Text(delayedMessage);
        } else {
          return Text(currentMessage);
        }
      });
}
```

Creating a state future variable will solve the issue. & most likely you will be needing & I will suggest as follows.

```dart
class ExampleF3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleF3({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleF3> createState() => _ExampleF3State();
}

class _ExampleF3State extends State<ExampleF3> {
  Future<String> delayedMessage() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)); //your upload operation,
    return 'Success';
  }

  late final future = delayedMessage();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          } else {
            return const Text('Loading...');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just had to modify some of it to add a navigator after the connectionState is done. Your own sample and simple explanation helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)